# Error no Banco de dados workbench, nascimento data, erro 0000-00-00

Tags: mysql

```
    create table pessoas(
    id int  not null  auto_increment,
    nome varchar(50) not null,
    nascimento date,
    sexo enum('M','F'),
    peso decimal(5,2),
    altura decimal(2,2),
    nacionalidade varchar(20) default 'Brasil',
    primary key (id)
)default charset = utf8;
```

Quando eu executo

```
insert into pessoas(id,nome,nascimento,sexo,peso,altura,nacionalidade)
values
(DEFAULT,'JOAO PAULO', 2018-02-25,'M',90,1.68, DEFAULT);
```

está dando esse resultado:

> JOAO PAULO   0000-00-00  M   90.00   0.99    Brasil

Está mostrando esse erro:

> 1    31  19:37:13    insert into pessoas(id,nome,nascimento,sexo,peso,altura,nacionalidade)
>    values
>    (DEFAULT,'JOAO PAULO', 2018-02-25,'M',90,1.68, DEFAULT)
>   1 row(s) affected, 2 warning(s):
>    1264 Out of range value adjusted for column 'nascimento' at row 1
>    1264 Out of range value adjusted for column 'altura' at row 1  0.015 sec

Onde estou errando?

Comment: Não seria a falta de aspas no valor da data de nascimento?

Comment: `'2018-02-25'`....

Comment: A falta aspas em outros valores tb.

Comment: João Paulo, o melhor jeito de agradecer é votando positivo nas respostas úteis e marcando uma resposta como "aceita"

Comment: mais aonde tem essa opçao?

Answer (score 2):

Além das aspas que estão faltando ao informar a data, você também está criando um campo (`altura`) com no máximo 2 números, sendo 2 de precisão (fica após o ponto).

Matematicamente falando, isso só é possível com números entre `0.01` e `0.99`. Portanto não serve para seu caso (altura em metros). Por isso você deve utilizar a estrutura da seguinte maneira.

```
CREATE TABLE pessoas(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  nascimento DATE,
  sexo ENUM('M', 'F'),
  peso DECIMAL(5, 2),

  /* Permite 3 números, sendo 2 deles de precisão (fica após a vírgula ou ponto) */
  altura DECIMAL(3, 2),

  nacionalidade VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT 'Brasil',
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
) DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

Ou você pode atualizar a tabela.

```
ALTER TABLE `pessoas` CHANGE `altura` `altura` DECIMAL(3,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

[**Demonstração**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8GFexXxrz9naZpacgYggPQ/0)

Comment: Valdeir tks....
Resolvido Deus abençoe.

Answer (score 0):

Faz o insert assim:

```
INSERT INTO pessoas (id, nome, nascimento, sexo, peso, altura, nacionalidade) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'JOAO PAULO', '2018-02-25', 'M', 90, 1.68, DEFAULT);
```

Comment: tks....deu certo aqui... vlw

Comment: PROBLEMA RESOLVIDO....